# 'true' not always converted to 1

Tags: c++, mfc, integer, boolean, type-conversion

I have this MFC code:

```
bool SomeBooleanValue;
...
m_ComboBox.ResetContent();
m_ComboBox.AddString("String1");
m_ComboBox.AddString("String2");
m_ComboBox.SetCurSel(SomeBooleanValue);
```

where m_ComboBox is a CComboBox object. And sometimes when SomeBooleanValue is true in CComboBox::SetCurSel functon instead of 1 I see value 252 during debugging:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE int CComboBox::SetCurSel(int nSelect)// here nSelect = 252!
    { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return (int)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, CB_SETCURSEL, nSelect, 0); }
```

As I know C++ standard says:

> An rvalue of type bool can be converted to an rvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true becoming one.

Any ideas why this happening?

Comment: `SomeBooleanValue` is not an rvalue here.

Comment: `SomeBooleanValue` isn't initialised.

Comment: 101010, I didn't made an attention to that... So when using boolean variables as an integer we can't be sure that they will be converted to 0 and 1?

πάντα ῥεῖ, SomeBooleanValue is initialized

Comment: @IKM2007 At least it's not in the code you show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct wording of the standard is *§ 4.7/p4 Integral conversions [conv.integral]:*

> If the destination type is bool, see 4.12. If the source type is bool,
>   the value false is converted to zero and the value true is converted
>   to one.

So yes, the excepted behaviour is for `bool` to be converted to zero if its value is `false` and to one if its value is true.

Also from §3.9.1/p6 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]:

> Values of type bool are either true or false.

But note [49] warns us:

> 49) Using a bool value in ways described by this International
>   Standard as “undefined,” such as by examining the value of an
>   uninitialized automatic object, might cause it to behave as if it is
>   neither true nor false.

That is, if you don't initialize a boolean the initial value will be unknown (i.e., arbitrary). Consequently, you get a behaviour described by the standard as "undefined".

Comment: Thank you for your response but I don't think that this is the case, because I initialize boolean value in constructor as false. The code that I provided is not the original one but the functionality is the same.  Also I see in debugger that I pass true to that function. I will investigate this case more carefully, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I have checked and you were right. The boolean that I used was copied from another structure where that another boolean was uninitialized. On debugger I saw that it's value is "true" but actually there was just a memory garbage there. After fixing that I am able to use that boolean as 0/1 integer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only chances to get this behaviour is:

1. your boolean variable is not initialized
2. you have another part that are writting over your variable  (a overrun for example)